# ElasticSearch: Host Responding with 403 Error for a Single Website

Tags: elasticsearch, http-status-code-403

We have a production box with several sites running on it, all of them using ElasticSearch.
All the sites have an http and https binding with a host, `www.<sitename>.co.za`, with their own ElasticSearch index, `<sitename>_index`. The ElasticSearch is setup as an application, `/ESP`, under the website and has a rewrite URL that directs it to the actual ElasticSearch on the machine.

I have added a new website with the same setup as the others, with http and https bindings with a host.
The site is running and seems to attach to the ElasticSearch correctly in the beginning. But when I try to actually search using the ElasticSearch, it gives me a 403 error.

[image]
[image]
The thing is, if I change the bindings to not have a host and only go by IP and port, the ElasticSearch works, and if I take the full URL request that fails from within the site and attempt it through Postman or even just in the browser directly, it works and returns data as expected.

**EDIT 1:**

I was asked for the rewrite rules for the `ESP` application. It is the same for the websites that work and the one that doesn't. The blacked out bit is the server IP.
[image]

**EDIT 2:**

I have set an existing, correctly setup website to use the new domain and the ElasticSearch still fails with the 403, with everything else still setup as it was.

The only differences in the passing and failing header is the authority, origin and referer.

**EDIT 3:**

I found the following under the `LogFiles` for the website. I don't know if this will be of any use.

```
2018-10-30 06:47:14 <IP> POST /ESP/<sitename>_index/_search size=20&X-ARR-CACHE-HIT=0&X-ARR-LOG-ID=d742707c-b48d-41a9-9b78-401822fe24e4&SERVER-STATUS=403 443 - 169.0.227.54 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/70.0.3538.77+Safari/537.36 https://www.<domain>.co.za/ 403 0 0 273
2018-10-30 06:47:14 <IP> HEAD /ESP/ _=1540881129027&X-ARR-CACHE-HIT=0&X-ARR-LOG-ID=532ffa02-b818-4e4f-bbbf-604f76fff4d4&SERVER-STATUS=400 443 - 169.0.227.54 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/70.0.3538.77+Safari/537.36 https://www.<domain>.co.za/ 400 0 0 82
```

Comment: Can you share your URL rewrite rules?

Comment: Edited the question to include the rule.

Answer (score 0):

I had previously seen solutions that spoke about the `elasticsearch.yml` config file but when Windows was tasked with finding it, it came up empty. I then assumed that this wasn't the answer.

It was.

In our `elasticsearch.yml` config file, there is a list `allow-origin`, which has the list of the other domains, as well as the IP, which is why the IP worked and the new domain did not.

I add the new domain to the list and it now works.